# Docker postgresql start directory in a volume

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, synology

Trying to run a postgresql db located in a directory (easily running from Mac or Ubuntu with `pg_ctl start -D pgdirectory/` )

```
docker network create pgnet

docker run -it --rm \
    --name pgdockerdb \
    --network pgnet \
    -p 5436:5432 \ #  postgres is running in 5432 locally
    -v /local/path/to/pgdb:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
    -e POSTGRES_DB=pgdb \
    -e POSTGRES_USER=pguser \
    -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sstrongggpass \
    postgres_image
```

I receive following answer (translated from spanish to english -> I don't know exact words that postgresql should write in english):

> ...first lines trying to create a new db...
> initdb: error: directory «/var/lib/postgresql/data» exists but it is not empty
> If you wan to create a new database cluster, erase or empty
> the directory «/var/lib/postgresql/data», or exec initdb
> with a different argument than «/var/lib/postgresql/data».
> db exited with code 1

I tried to include a sh with `pg_ctl start -D .` in volume /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

I tried to include PUID and PGID enviroment variables in docker-compose.yml from `id $user` (root, user or 999 [because docker y chowning files to that user])

Worst thing is that one time worked but when y copied the up-to-date db, never worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I realized that `PG_VERSION` wasn't in my directory so I created it. Then Postgres asked for more missing folders so, finally I suggest to create a new database to compare data structure to find if your directory is well formed.

I had a problem translating the files indeed, so I restored a previous version and it's working flawlessly.